# Query cannot be translated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ef-core-5.0

I have the following class:

```
class document
{
    int Id;
    List<Tag> Tags;
}

class Tag
{
    int Id;
}
```

I want to get all the documents that have at least one of the tags that the user selects.

I have written the following linq query:

```
List<int> tagIds = tags.Select (x => x.Id).ToList ();

query.Where (doc => tagIds.Any (x => doc.Tags.Select (y => y.Id).Contains (x)));
```

If I execute it against a list of documents, it works, but if I execute it against a sqlite database using efcore 5 I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<DemaDocument>()
    .Where(d => __tagIds_0
        .Any(x => DbSet<Dictionary<string, object>>("DemaDocumentDemaTag")
            .Where(d0 => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(d, "Id") != null && object.Equals(
                objA: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(d, "Id"), 
                objB: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(d0, "DocumentsId")))
            .Join(
                inner: DbSet<DemaTag>(), 
                outerKeySelector: d0 => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(d0, "TagsId"), 
                innerKeySelector: d1 => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(d1, "Id"), 
                resultSelector: (d0, d1) => new TransparentIdentifier<Dictionary<string, object>, DemaTag>(
                    Outer = d0, 
                    Inner = d1
                ))
            .Select(ti => ti.Inner.Id)
            .Any(p => p == x)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'
```

How can I rewrite the query using fluent LINQ so that it will work? Is it possible, or do I have to retrieve the documents in memory and then run the query? This would not be ideal, because the documents will grow over time...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried inverting the query: `query.Where(doc => doc.Tags.Any(x => tagIds.Contains(x.Id)))` ? This might allow the `Contains` to we translated to a `IN` statement, since the tagsIds list is constant for the query.

Comment: It works like a charm! Do you mind wrtiing this as the answer and explaining me why it works so that in the future I'll be able to adapt this solution to other problems? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.Contains` should be translated as a SQL `IN` statement, i.e. `x IN 1, 2, 3`. This requires the list to be constant. In your example `doc.Tags.Select (y => y.Id)` is unique for each document, so it cannot be translated to a constant list.

What you are doing is more or less checking if two lists intersects, so we should be able to reverse the order of the two lists:

```
query.Where(doc => doc.Tags.Any(x => tagIds.Contains(x.Id)))
```

Now the tagIds is constant for the query, and the `.Contains` statement can be properly translated.

Comment: Can you please check my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65645691/the-linq-expression-outer-apply-projection-mapping-in-ef-net-core-5-exception